# Which EU material tells Count Dooku's story before Attack of the Clones

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order

I want to read Count Dooku's back story (Primarily, how he quit the Jedi and fell to the darkside, and his relationship with Sifo-Dyas, Palpatine etc..) his [page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku) on the wikia covers the *what* nicely, but I can't work out from the references which book / comic they happen in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am reading the book *Darth Plagueis* right now, and while Dooku's not got a *ton* of screen time, he is certainly in it and his relationship between the Jedi Council, Sifo-Dyas, Palpatine, and Plagueis is investigated. It's been a pretty good read, actually.